# Remove Google Analytics text

Tags: html, google-analytics-api

I have installed google analytics code for my website in footer scripts. Google analytics code dynamically adds "google+" text. How can I remove it or hide it for users?

I want to remove or hide google+ text.

Comment: What?? Google Analytics should **not** be injecting visible content into your page.

Comment: To rephrase @esqew, Google Analytics **DOES NOT** inject visible content into your page. **Post your code.**

Comment: Are you asking about seeing google js calls within your view source?  I'm really not sure what you could mean otherwise as @CaseyFalk stated, google analytics does not add anything visible to the view of your page.

Comment: I can't able to post the image. But Google+ is visible in my page.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `display: none;` in CSS on the element.